# Moving 4GB file from Android to PC

Tags: file-transfer, iso-image

I have an ISO file, which is about 4GB, stored in my phone.I want to move that file to my PC, but I don't have a USB cable. My PC doesn't have WiFi either (I connect it to the internet via Ethernet cable).

How can i move the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install on your phone [FTPServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer&hl=en), turn WiFi on your phone (it should be connected to your home network where your PC is living), run `FTPServer`, run file explorer on windows and place in navigation bar address of your phone(FTPServer will show you IP and port that it listening on) as `ftp://user@ip.ip.ip.ip:PortNumber` and download anything you want from your phone

Here is a settings you need to setup when you start FTServer

- Username - it is what you will use in Explorer in place of "user"
  from command above
- Password - I guess it self explanatory
- Port - It is what you need to substitute in "PortNumber" in command
  above
- Default dir - it is a folder on your phone that you going to share on your local network
- Allowed connection - You need to enable access for your WiFi SSID
  (name of your WiFi that you see when connecting to your local
  network).    It is a security feature, FTServer will accept
  connections only from allowed WiFi networks

[image: FTPServer]

Comment: Does it require internet connection while downloading?

Comment: No, if you connected over WiFi to your local network it doesn't require internet, everything transferring over your local network. You can even disconnect cable from WAN port on your router

Comment: how can i run ftpserver?

Comment: @user694722 Did you not read the rather clear instructions in the answer?

Comment: yeah i am a noob :(

Comment: @user694722 I updated my answer, reload this page to get update

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- borrow a USB cable or buy one ($1-2)
- borrow a USB SD card reader and insert the card into it
- borrow a laptop and let it intermediate the transfer
- just upload the file from your phone (to something like mega.nz) and download it on the PC (but make sure you have enough GB on your internet subscription plan for the phone)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to buy a USB cable.

My second choice would be to connect an SD card reader to your PC. Copy the file to your phone's SD card (if it's not already on it) and transfer it to your PC.

Failing those, you could set up a shared network folder on your PC, and use a file explorer on Android that can access UNC shares. One example is [Total Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander) with the [LAN plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.tcplugins.LAN).

Of course your router should be set up to allow communication between the two devices, and both should be connected to it (by cable or WiFi).

Comment: I do have a USB cable but my computer doesn't recognize my phone..I tried another cable but still same issue..Anyways, I will try your other suggestions thanks!

Comment: For the USB connection to work, you may have to manually install a driver for Android on your PC.

Comment: Can you please explain more regarding Total Commander and its plugin\?

Comment: If you have a USB cabe... why did you say you didn't? Your entire problem is now a different one from the question you asked :/ This is what's known as an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @Tetsujin Because it doesn't work so I wanted an alternative solution

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah I just got +8 rep..thinking of staying here for some time

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, and your Computer supports it, you can try sending it via Bluetooth. This will be quite slow and you may need an app like Bluetooth File Transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use free webtools such as Takeafile.com, send-anywhere.com o filepizza.com or file.pizza

I would recommend the two first, as they are more 'profesional'